# Unsupported minor.major version 51.0

Tags: java, selenium

While running Java program it is giving me and minor.major version mismatch error. I have JRE6.0 installed in my PC and no JDK version installed.
The exception which I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: otaclient/ClassFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at Intergrate.main(Intergrate.java:13)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you typed in the subject of this Q, and all those things popped up that answered it? You should look at them.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be compiled on JDK 1.7. You need to be upgrade your JRE to run this code

Answer (score 1):

That class *is* compiled with a JDK 7, try it yourself. Run:

```
javap -verbose otaclient.ClassFactory
```

If you see '**major version: 51**', it is was compiled with a JDK 1.7, see the [Version of Class File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you're trying to run was compiled with JDK 1.7, so you should upgrade your machine JRE to 1.7 or 1.8 to run it.